# Why my signal-slot is slower than QThreadPool+new+delete?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

I was reading Qt's Signals & Slots [1] and noticed that it claims signals and slots have much lower overhead than any new or delete operation. So I did a test:

```
#include <cmath>

#include <QtCore/QAtomicInt>
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QtCore/QElapsedTimer>
#include <QtCore/QMetaObject>
#include <QtCore/QMetaMethod>
#include <QtCore/QObject>
#include <QtCore/QRunnable>
#include <QtCore/QTextStream>
#include <QtCore/QThread>
#include <QtCore/QThreadPool>
#include <QtCore/QTimer>
#include <QtCore/QVector>

using std::pow;

constexpr int const maxThreadCount(16);
constexpr int const maxIteration(100000);
constexpr int const maxPiDigit(1000);

void calcPi()
{
    double sum(0);
    for (int k(0); k < maxPiDigit; ++k) {
        double a(4.0 / (k * 8 + 1));
        double b(2.0 / (k * 8 + 4));
        double c(1.0 / (k * 8 + 5));
        double d(1.0 / (k * 8 + 6));
        sum += pow(16, -k) * (a - b - c -d);
    }
    QTextStream out(stdout);
    out << sum << endl;
}

class CalcPiWithQObject : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        CalcPiWithQObject(QObject *parent = NULL);

    public slots:
        void start();

    signals:
        void finished();
}; // CalcPiWithQObject

CalcPiWithQObject::CalcPiWithQObject(QObject *parent):
    QObject(parent)
{}

void CalcPiWithQObject::start()
{
    calcPi();
    finished();
}

class CalcPiWithQRunnable : public QRunnable
{
    private:
        static QAtomicInt count_;

    public:
        CalcPiWithQRunnable(QThreadPool *parent);

        void run() override;

    private:
        QThreadPool *parent_;
}; // CalcPiWithQRunnable

QAtomicInt CalcPiWithQRunnable::count_(maxThreadCount);

CalcPiWithQRunnable::CalcPiWithQRunnable(QThreadPool *parent):
    QRunnable(),
    parent_(parent)
{
    setAutoDelete(false);
}

void CalcPiWithQRunnable::run()
{
    calcPi();
    if (count_.fetchAndAddOrdered(1) < maxIteration) {
        parent_->start(new CalcPiWithQRunnable(parent_));
    }
    delete this;
}

class PiTest : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        PiTest(QObject *parent = NULL);

    public slots:
        void start();
        void nextQObjectCall();

    private:
        QVector<QThread *> threads_;
        QVector<CalcPiWithQObject *> calc_;
        QThreadPool *threadPool_;
        QElapsedTimer timer_;
        int threadCount_;
        int jobCount_;
}; // PiTest

PiTest::PiTest(QObject *parent):
    QObject(parent),
    threads_(maxThreadCount),
    calc_(maxThreadCount),
    threadPool_(new QThreadPool(this)),
    threadCount_(maxThreadCount),
    jobCount_(maxThreadCount)
{
    threadPool_->setMaxThreadCount(maxThreadCount);
    for (int i(0); i < maxThreadCount; ++i) {
        threads_[i] = new QThread();
        calc_[i] = new CalcPiWithQObject();
        calc_[i]->moveToThread(threads_[i]);
        QObject::connect(calc_[i], &CalcPiWithQObject::finished,
                         this, &PiTest::nextQObjectCall,
                         Qt::QueuedConnection);
        QObject::connect(threads_[i], &QThread::started,
                         calc_[i], &CalcPiWithQObject::start,
                         Qt::QueuedConnection);
    }
}

void PiTest::start()
{
    timer_.start();
    for (int i(0); i < maxThreadCount; ++i) {
        threadPool_->start(new CalcPiWithQRunnable(threadPool_));
    }
    threadPool_->waitForDone();
    int timePassed(timer_.elapsed());
    QTextStream out(stdout);
    out << "QThreadPool: " << timePassed << endl;
    timer_.restart();
    for (int i(0); i < maxThreadCount; ++i) {
        threads_[i]->start();
    }
}

static QMetaMethod nextCall(PiTest::staticMetaObject.method(PiTest::staticMetaObject.indexOfMethod("start")));

void PiTest::nextQObjectCall()
{
    jobCount_++;
    if (jobCount_ < maxIteration) {
        nextCall.invoke(sender(), Qt::QueuedConnection);
        QMetaObject::invokeMethod(sender(), "start",
                                  Qt::QueuedConnection);
        return;
    }
    threadCount_--;
    if (threadCount_ == 0) {
        for (int i(0); i < maxThreadCount; ++i) {
            threads_[i]->quit();
        }
        int timePassed(timer_.elapsed());
        QTextStream out(stdout);
        out << "QThread: " << timePassed << endl;
        qApp->quit();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    PiTest *bench(new PiTest(qApp));
    QTimer::singleShot(0, bench, SLOT(start()));
    return qApp->exec();
}

#include "main_moc.cpp"
```

And I ran the test on an idle 20-core computer:

```
/usr/lib64/qt5/bin/moc -o main_moc.cpp main.cpp
clang++ -std=c++11 -fPIE -O2 -march=native -I/usr/include/qt5/ -L/usr/lib64/qt5 -lQt5Core -o bench main.cpp
./bench > test.out
grep QThread test.out
```

And here are the results:

```
QThreadPool: 4803
QThread: 9285
```

I tried different parameters, with longer pi calculation and less jobs, or vice versa, but the results were around the same. QThread+signal/slots was always lagging behind. With larger numbers of jobs, QThreadPool+new/delete can easily outperform QThread by up to 10-fold.

I feel somehow awkward about my benchmark code. Did I misunderstand something here? If signal/slot is faster than new/delete, what's the problem with my benchmark?

Thank you.

[1] http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html

Comment: @JosephMalicke, I think I am testing signal slots here. I might have made mistakes here. That's why I am asking this question. The purpose is to test signal/slots vs new/delete across different threads.

Comment: I did a test with 100 pi jobs with 10000000 iterations. That makes QThreadPool worse than QThread. I don't know why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a difference in signal performance depending on the connection type. When you create inter-thread connections, the connection is queued, and uses an event loop to schedule itself, and the event loop in Qt is not only fairly slow, but last time I checked it didn't provide any way to increase its update rate.

This makes signals across threads really slow, I've had cases where I had fine grained concurrency which suffered performance hit from multithreading rather than a performance boost.

Just to give you an idea of the difference between direct and queued connections:

```
#define COUNT 5000
class Ping : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_SIGNAL void pong(uint);
public slots: void ping(uint c) { if (c < COUNT) emit pong(++c); else qDebug() << t.nsecsElapsed(); }
};

//...

QObject::connect(&p1, SIGNAL(pong(uint)), &p2, SLOT(ping(uint)), Qt::DirectConnection);
QObject::connect(&p2, SIGNAL(pong(uint)), &p1, SLOT(ping(uint)), Qt::DirectConnection);

//...

p1.ping(0);
```

Results:

```
Direct connection (in same thread)    - 570504 nsec
Queued connection (in same thread)    - 29670333 nsec
Queued connection (different threads) - 53343054 nsec
```

As you can plainly see, an inter-thread connection is almost **100 times slower** than a direct one. And I suspect that documentation you linked to refers to a direct connection.

All in all, I'd say your test is a total mess. You should really streamline it, make it simple and focus on the issue you raise.

Lastly, direct connections might be faster than new/delete, but queued connections most certainly are not, they are much slower, and definitely the key factor behind the varying performance. The claim made in the documentation you linked to has **absolutely nothing** to do with `QThread + worker` vs `QRunnable + thread pool` performance. And finally, in **both** cases you use **both** dynamic memory allocation/deallocation and queued connections.

Comment: I think I misunderstood here. Thanks for the clarification. I was unable to construct a benchmark to decouple signal-slot part from new-delete part, since I think they are "different approach" here.